# Initial Value Problem; Existence of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Let's consider the initial value problem

$$ y^{\prime}(t) = f(t)y(t), y(0)=1 $$

where, $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is  continuous, Then the IVP has

(a) infinitely many solutions for some $f$

(b) a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$

(c) no solution in $\mathbb{R}$ for some $f$

(d) a solution in an interval containing $0$ but not on  $\mathbb{R}$ for some $f$

We have to find the correct options. Can we do it like:

$$ y^{\prime}(t) = f(t)y(t)$$

$$y=c e^{\int f(t)dt}$$

$$y=c e^{g(t)}; \int f(t)dt=g(t) $$ on putting initial condition, we can find the value for $c$. In that case,can  we  reject options a and c. Any help, Please

Comment: Do you know the Picard-Lindelöf theorem?

Comment: No, I don't know! If it helps then please state it to explain the answer.